# How to Get Set of Partition Column(s) Values with Spark DataFrameWriter.partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I'd like to use Spark `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy()` to write to AWS S3. It, of course, writes a separate directory branch for each unique combination of partition column values.

Is there any way to get from Spark which partition column value combinations existed in the DataFrame, i.e. were written? Without querying the "filesystem" (AWS S3 object store).

Comment: do you need to know exact partitions that were written or just want to ensure that written partitions are, let's say, between 2 different values? `.filter(...)` would work on partition parameters for the second case (to restrict output to specific subset), but I realize it's a bit different from what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to partition say `a` and `b`, you can just query your dataframe `df.select($"a",$"b").distinct.show()`, this gives you the folders that will be created.

Comment: Will this do a separate computation? I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: it most likely will compute twice (distinct once, then normal partitioned write will happen - so distinct adds to your job load). to avoid recomputation of `df` use at least `df.persist()` if DF is expensive to compute and you see performance issues coming from this.